# Object Oriented Polymorphism in Haskell

Tags: oop, haskell, polymorphism

So I have seen questions that ask how do you do Object Oriented Programming in Haskell, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184286/object-oriented-programming-in-haskell) for example.  To which the answer is along the lines of "type classes are like interfaces but not quite".  In particular a type class doesn't allow a list to be built of all those types.  E.g. we can't do `map show [1, 1.4, "hello"]` despite that having a logical result.

Given some time I wondered if it wasn't possible to do better.  So I had an attempt at coding polymorphism for a simple Shape class, which can be found below (if you like sanity probably better to stop reading now, and apologies for it being so long).

```
module Shapes (
          Shape(..)
        , Point
        , Circle(..)
        , Triangle(..)
        , Square(..)
        , location
        , area
) where

data Point = Point {
          xcoord :: Float
        , ycoord :: Float
} deriving (Read, Show)

data Shape = CircleT Circle | PolygonT Polygon deriving (Read, Show)

data Circle = Circle {
          cLocation :: Point
        , cRadius :: Float
} deriving (Read, Show)

data Polygon = SquareT Square | TriangleT Triangle deriving (Read, Show)

data Square = Square {
          sLocation :: Point
        , sLength :: Float
} deriving (Read, Show)

-- only right angled triangles for ease of implementation!
data Triangle = Triangle {
          tLocation :: Point
        , tSide1 :: Float
        , tSide2 :: Float
} deriving (Read, Show)

class ShapeIf a where
        location :: a -> Point
        area :: a -> Float

instance ShapeIf Shape where
        location (CircleT a) = location a
        location (PolygonT a) = location a
        area (CircleT a) = area a
        area (PolygonT a) = area a

instance ShapeIf Polygon where
        location (SquareT a) = location a
        location (TriangleT a) = location a
        area (SquareT a) = area a
        area (TriangleT a) = area a

instance ShapeIf Square where
        location = sLocation
        area a = (sLength a) ^ 2

instance ShapeIf Circle where
        location = cLocation
        area a = pi * (cRadius a) ^ 2

instance ShapeIf Triangle where
        location = tLocation
        area a = 0.5 * (tSide1 a) * (tSide2 a)
```

Despite all the madness this ends up having some quite nice properties: I can have a list of shapes and I can map functions over them that make sense (like location and area).  But also if I have a particular Shape (say a Triangle) then I can also call area just on that.  But it is horrendous.  I don't like the code at all (indeed I'm sure it would be much shorter in any object oriented programming language).

So where have I gone wrong?  How can this be made nicer?  Saying "don't think in terms of objects" is nice, but this seems to have several applications (e.g. a list of characters in a role playing game ... who have some shared attributes but different abilities, or GUI programming where objects tend to make sense).

Comment: What's wrong with a `data Shape = Shape { location :: Point, area :: Float }` type, and a `class IsShape s where toShape :: s -> Shape` typeclass instead?  You can then make a different data type for every kind of shape you want, then just write the instance for `IsShape` so that you can call `toShape` on it.  The values for location and area, if the need to be computed, won't be until they're needed thanks to laziness.  You have to do the type casts manually, but this isn't new to OOP anyway.  Then any function that uses a `Shape` has all the same information as if it were `ShapeIf`.

Comment: @bheklilr: That's great if all we want to do is have location and area attributes.  But your class is very lossy (a square and a triangle in the same position are now identical shape records).  For example the method `display :: Shape -> IO()` is going to be very difficult for you to write with this new type.

Comment: @dave with bhklilr's approach you write `data Shape = Shape { location :: Point, area :: Float, display :: IO () }`. Yes, your code will get compile errors when you add functions, but this is the same with added abstract methods in Java. In both cases the compile error is helpful.

Comment: @dave as Franky points out, you can add another function to the `Shape` type for that.  I'll type up my response as as answer to help make it more clear.

Answer (score 3):

You can use simple data types for this purpose without resorting to typeclasses.  If you do want to use typeclasses, it's better to use it to describe a conversion to your base type rather than having it include all the implementation details:

```
data Point = Point
    { xcoord :: Float
    , ycoord :: Float
    } deriving (Eq, Read, Show)

data Shape = Shape
    { shapeLocation :: Point
    , shapeArea :: Float
    } deriving (Eq, Show)
```

This might be the only two types you need, depending on your application, since you could write functions

```
circle :: Point -> Float -> Shape
circle loc radius = Shape loc $ pi * r * r

square :: Point -> Float -> Shape
square loc sLength = Shape loc $ sLength * sLength

triangle :: Point -> Float -> Float -> Shape
triangle loc base height = Shape loc $ 0.5 * base * height
```

But maybe you want to preserve those arguments.  In which case, write a data type for each

```
data Circle = Circle
    { cLocation :: Point
    , cRadius :: Float
    } deriving (Eq, Show)

data Square = Square
    { sLocation :: Point
    , sLength :: Float
    } deriving (Eq, Show)

data Triangle = Triangle
    { tLocation :: Point
    , tBase :: Float
    , tHeight :: Float
    } deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Then for convenience, I'd use a typeclass here to define `toShape`:

```
class IsShape s where
    toShape :: s -> Shape

instance IsShape Shape where
    toShape = id

instance IsShape Circle where
    toShape (Circle loc radius) = Shape loc $ pi * radius * radius

instance IsShape Square where
    toShape (Square loc sideLength) = Shape loc $ sideLength * sideLength

instance IsShape Triangle where
    toShape (Triangle loc base height) = Shape loc $ 0.5 * base * height
```

But now there's the problem that you have to convert each type to `Shape` in order to get its area or location in a more generic way, except you can just add the functions

```
location :: IsShape s => s -> Point
location = shapeLocation . toShape

area :: IsShape s => s -> Float
area = shapeArea . toShape
```

I would keep these out of the `IsShape` class so that they can't be re-implemented, this is similar to functions like `replicateM` that work on all `Monad`s, but aren't part of the `Monad` typeclass.  Now you can write code like

```
twiceArea :: IsShape s => s -> Float
twiceArea = (2 *) . area
```

And this is fine when you're only operating on a single shape argument.  If you want to operate on a collection of them:

```
totalArea :: IsShape s => [s] -> Float
totalArea = sum . map area
```

So that you don't have to rely on existentials to build a collection of them you can instead have

```
> let p = Point 0 0
> totalArea [toShape $ Circle p 5, toShape $ Square p 10, toShape $ Triangle p 10 20]
278.53983
> totalArea $ map (Square p) [1..10]
385.0
```

This gives you the flexibility to work on a list of objects of different types, or on a list of just a single type using the same function and absolutely no language extensions.

Bear in mind that this is still trying to implement a sort of object model in a strictly functional language, something that isn't going to be completely ideal, but considering this allows you to have

- multiple "interfaces" (conversions to different types)
- generics (`totalArea :: IsShape s => [s] -> Float`)
- sealed methods if you were to use a smart constructor for `Shape` and add more methods to it then alias them like with `area` and `location`
- unsealed methods if you just allowed those to be set by the smart constructor
- public and private are set by module exports

and probably some other OOP paradigms, all with really less code than it would take in Java or C#, the only difference is that the code isn't all grouped together.  This has it's benefits and disadvantages, such as being able to define new instances and data types more freely, but making the code somewhat more difficult to navigate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [existential quantification](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Existentially_quantified_types) for such purposes:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data Point = Point {
          xcoord :: Float
        , ycoord :: Float
} deriving (Read, Show)

data Circle = Circle {
          cLocation :: Point
        , cRadius :: Float
} deriving (Read, Show)

data Square = Square {
          sLocation :: Point
        , sLength :: Float
} deriving (Read, Show)

data Triangle = Triangle {
          tLocation :: Point
        , tSide1 :: Float
        , tSide2 :: Float
} deriving (Read, Show)

class ShapeIf a where
        location :: a -> Point
        area :: a -> Float

instance ShapeIf Square where
        location = sLocation
        area a = (sLength a) ^ 2

instance ShapeIf Circle where
        location = cLocation
        area a = pi * (cRadius a) ^ 2

instance ShapeIf Triangle where
        location = tLocation
        area a = 0.5 * (tSide1 a) * (tSide2 a)

data Shape = forall a. ShapeIf a => Shape a

instance ShapeIf Shape where
    location (Shape s) = location s
    area     (Shape s) = area s

p = Point 0 0

shlist :: [Shape]        
shlist = [Shape (Square p 0), Shape (Circle p 1), Shape (Triangle p 2 3)]

main = print $ map area shlist
```

But note, that there are no downcasts in Haskell, so it's not a direct analogue to Java-style subtyping. Have a look at [this](http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/) also.

Comment: This is frequently identified as an antipattern. See, e.g., [Luke Palmer's much-cited post](http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/).

Comment: @Christian Conkle, I've mentioned it in the last sentence in my answer. I don't agree with it, however.

Comment: On further thought, I realize that an assumption behind the antipattern verdict is that `Shape` is isomorphic, i.e. contains no more information than, `(Point, Float)`, and so why not just store `[(Point, Float)]` explicitly? But in the presence of `Data.Typeable`, you *can* recover and work with the true type (with limitations). In other words, if you add `Typeable a` to the constraint list on `Shape`, you *can* downcast with `cast`, so long as you respect the scope of the existential type variable.

Comment: @Christian Conkle, the reason why I don't like the record-with-functions approach is that it imposes on you a need to precompute everything, before you actually need it. And that breaks semantics. Look at the @bheklilr answer: why should you convert something to the `Shape` datatype to compute its area? Let's say I'm already have `Circle`, `Square` and other datatypes, among with some typeclass, that contains different functions, and I have already implemented instances for these datatypes. Now I want to store some Shapes in a list. Should I completely rewrite the whole development?

Comment: No, I shouldn't. There are existential types for this — ad hoc solution, that works, and doesn't impose on me a need to change anything.

Comment: @user3237465 " the reason why I don't like the record-with-functions approach is that it imposes on you a need to precompute everything, before you actually need it." - Nope, laziness.  You have to have the computation there, but nothing is actually computed until it's needed by your program.  The computation has to be defined somewhere, what's wrong with defining it within a record?  "why should you convert something to the Shape datatype to compute its area?" - The same reason why you'd want a `Shape` interface in OOP, so you can have a single function that acts on multiple types.

Comment: @bheklilr, "Nope, laziness." — I'm talking about semantics, not effectiveness. But it's a matter of taste. "The same reason why you'd want a Shape interface in OOP, so you can have a single function that acts on multiple types." — First thing, that comes to my mind, when I want this kind of polymorphism in FP, is creating a typeclass. This is simple and idiomatic. ExTypes is the next step in this direction, while record-with-functions approach implies, that you need to extensively plan your development from the very beginning.

Comment: @user3237465 [The semantics aren't that different really](https://gist.github.com/bheklilr/931303e5a40e699c9e3e).  The "interface" takes a few more lines to set up, but it could be automated using TemplateHaskell pretty easily.  Considering that your solution still has to wrap the values in a `Shape` constructor in order to store them in a list, why not go the route of `toShape` being part of that interface?  You don't have to rely on an extension that honestly confuses a lot of beginners.  Both solutions are equivalent, but one of them works without having to resort to tricks.

Answer (score 1):

After being pointed to [this](http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/) blog post about existential quantification being an anti-pattern (which I had reinvented in a slightly clumsier way), I had a try at a rewrite and came up with:

```
module Shapes (Shape(), Point, Circle(..), Triangle(..), Square(..), location, area) where

data Point = Point {
          xcoord :: Float
        , ycoord :: Float
} deriving (Read, Show)

data Shape = Shape {
      location :: Point
    , shape :: ShapeT
}

data ShapeT = CircleT Circle | PolygonT Polygon deriving (Read, Show)

data Circle = Circle {
          cRadius :: Float
} deriving (Read, Show)

data Polygon = SquareT Square | TriangleT Triangle deriving (Read, Show)

data Square = Square {
          sLength :: Float
} deriving (Read, Show)

-- only right angled triangles for ease of implementation!
data Triangle = Triangle {
          tSide1 :: Float
        , tSide2 :: Float
} deriving (Read, Show)

square :: Point -> Float -> Shape
square p l = Shape p (PolygonT $ SquareT (Square l))

circle :: Point -> Float -> Shape
circle p r = Shape p (CircleT (Circle r))

triangle :: Point -> Float -> Float -> Shape
triangle p s1 s2 = Shape p (PolygonT $ TriangleT (Triangle s1 s2))

area :: Shape -> Float
area = area' . shape

area' (PolygonT (SquareT (a))) = (sLength a) ^ 2
area' (CircleT (a)) = pi * (cRadius a) ^ 2
area' (PolygonT (TriangleT (a))) = 0.5 * (tSide1 a) * (tSide2 a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get madder.

Analysed in Haskell terms, declaring a  Java-style class does a number of things:

1. Declares the existence of a set of types that share a common interface, requiring that all members of the set are also members of all the base classes' associated type sets
2. Declares a concrete record type
3. Declares the new data type is a member of the new set of types, and all the base classes' associated sets
4. Declares an existential type, able to hold any concrete type that is a member of the new set of types

Whew. Features like interfaces, final classes, etc, basically allow you to skip parts of that list if you don't need/want the whole bundle. And on top of that, Java-style classes *also* provide a module system, which I'm not going to address at all.

Seen this way, you *can* get all of the above in Haskell if you use an "OO design pattern" to implement each of them yourself. But in a language like Java there's a *lot* of help that is provided by the language, which would manifest in Haskell as sensible defaults and syntactic sugar if it were present. An example is inheritance, which is basically automatic containment of superclass records within subclass records and automatic delegation to superclass implementations from subclass implementations. Haskell will give you none of this help, so everything must be explicit and the "OO design pattern" comes out incredibly verbose.

Part 1 is pretty easy to see; a set of types sharing a common interface is what a type class **is**. Haskell allows us to put superclass constraints on the new type class too. Done.

Part 2 is also straightforward; just declare a new data type holding all the member variables. Note that if you intend to be able to "inherit" from this "class" and use the same assessors to get member variables out, you'll want to have those as part of the *type class*, not just use Haskell's record syntax to declare them for you. And if you're "inheriting" from other "OO pattern" classes, you'll want to included their data types as members of your new data type.

Part 3 is where the lack of help from the language starts to get tedious. You need to implement instances for *each* type class implied by the OO inheritance hierarchy, going all the way up (i.e. not just the immediate bases). If you're not overriding "methods" then this will be extremely mechanical and tedious, because you can just delegate all the "inherited" methods to the contained member data of the base classes (which should already have all the needed instances if you're following the pattern). This is manually implementing what OO inheritance defaults for you.

Part 4 is the doozy. OO programmers are masters of existentially quantified types, they just don't know it. Haskell supports existentially quantified types, but only through extensions, and a little awkwardly. And the language, idioms, and libraries aren't really expecting you to make really heavy use of existential types, so you'll start to experience a lot of friction using them; mostly in the form of annoying type errors that go away when you manage to figure out the correct type to write explicitly, and occasionally you'll need to explicitly eta expand (i.e. turn `f = foo` into `f x = foo x`, where the logic of higher order functions should say that makes no difference).

You might think that we shouldn't need the existential types, since type-class-constrained type variables should be enough to allow code to work on any member of the type class. The trouble is that a type variable constrained by a type class must be instantiated at each call to any *one* type in the type class (and the choice is made by the caller, not by whatever data happens to arrive at runtime).

This is why type classes don't allow you to use heterogenous lists; although the type `Shape a => [a]` can hold objects of *any* type that implements Shape, there is only one single type variable for all the elements of the list, so they all must be the same "any type that implements Shape". An existential type is a wrapper that contains data with a type variable but where the wrapper does not itself have that type variable in its own type. This allows you to just have a list of `[Shape]`, where it's `Shape` that internally contains a `ShapeI a => a`.

I think I've exhausted how well I can explain this without example code, so here goes. Warning, it's pretty ugly:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification, GADTs, RankNTypes #-}


newtype Point = Point (Double, Double)
  deriving (Show, Eq)


-- The Shape common interface
-- Shape is just an interface, so no member data type
class ShapeI a
  where area :: a -> Double

-- The Shape existential reference
data Shape 
  where Shape :: ShapeI a => a -> Shape 


-- The Polygon common interface: 'subtype' of Shape
-- Polygon is just an interface, so no member data type
class ShapeI a => PolygonI a
  where vertexes :: a -> [Point]

-- The Polygon existential reference
data Polygon
  where Polygon :: PolygonI a => a -> Polygon


-- The Circle common interface
class ShapeI a => CircleI a
  where centre :: a -> Point 
        radius :: a -> Double

-- The Circle existential reference
data Circle
  where Circle :: CircleI a => a -> Circle

-- The Circle member data type
data CircleM = CircleM Point Double
  deriving (Show, Eq)

-- Circles are Shapes
instance ShapeI CircleM
  where area (CircleM _ r) = pi * r * r 

-- Circles are Circles
instance CircleI CircleM
  where centre (CircleM c _) = c
        radius (CircleM _ r) = r


data Colour = Med | Blue
  deriving (Show, Eq)

-- The ColouredCircle member data type
-- ColouredCircle is final, so not bothering with a type class or existential reference
data CircleColouredM = CircleColouredM CircleM Colour
  deriving (Show, Eq)


-- ColouredCircles are Shapes
instance ShapeI CircleColouredM
  where area (CircleColouredM circle _) = area circle

-- ColouredCircles are Circles
-- Note there is no actual implementation logic here, ColouredCircleM implements
-- the Circle methods purely by using Circle's implementations
instance CircleI CircleColouredM
  where centre (CircleColouredM circle _) = centre circle
        radius (CircleColouredM circle _) = radius circle


-- The Triangle member data type
-- Triangle is final, so not bothering with a type class or existential refernce
data TriangleM = TriangleM Point Point Point
  deriving (Show, Eq)

instance ShapeI TriangleM
  where area = const 7 -- In this hypothetical universe, all triangles have area 7

instance PolygonI TriangleM
  where vertexes (TriangleM a b c) = [a, b, c]
```

Given all that:

```
-- Heterogenous list of different types of objects which are all Circles
circles :: [Circle]
circles = [Circle (CircleM (Point (3, 7)) 2), Circle (CircleColouredM (CircleM (Point (8, 1)) 1) Blue)]


-- Casts a Circle existential to a Shape existential
-- Note that the object *indside* the existential reference is the same; we're
-- just treating it as a Shape now
circleToShape :: Circle -> Shape
circleToShape (Circle c) = Shape c


-- Heterogenous list of different types of objects which are all Shapes
-- Note we are able to uniformly cast the circles list to shapes in order store
-- them in this list, even though they're not all the same type already
shapes :: [Shape]
shapes = [Shape (TriangleM (Point (0, 0)) (Point (10, 0)) (Point (0, 10)))] ++ map circleToShape circles


-- Helper function; can apply any function that is polymorphic in ShapeI to a
-- Shape existential; the explicit type is necessary, because it's a rank 2 type
apply :: (forall a. ShapeI a => a -> b) -> Shape -> b
apply f (Shape x) = f x


areas = map (apply area) shapes
```

So you see we do get heterogenous lists  (or in general, types which can independently hold any member of a "class" and allow access to that class' common interface), OO style inheritance hierarchies (though with manual boilerplate to inherit methods unchanged), and even upcasting.

Another issue you'll likely run into is how strict Haskell is about type discipline. You won't be able to downcast; in fact you won't be able to refer to *any* property of a `Shape` existential other than what's implied by the `ShapeI` interface; all knowledge about what it particularly contains is gone.

This also means that the `shapes` list is close to useless; the only meaningful thing we can do with it is `map (apply area) shapes`, so we might as well have done away with the masses of boilerplate and just created a list of `Double` in the first place. Also, the root class in OO languages tends to provide a surprising amount of functionality; you can `toString` arbitrary objects in Java, compare them for equality, etc. You get *none* of that here. Once something's an existential reference, you can access *nothing* but what its constraints say you can. No `Show` constraint, no `show` method (even though all of the types I've used here *do* implement `Show`). Likewise, no `Eq` constraint, no `==` function; and that probably wouldn't work as you'd like here because (being an idiomatic Haskell function and not expecting to deal with existentials emulating OO class heirarchies) `==` only works on two values guaranteed to be of the same type, and the existential reference gives up all knowledge about being of any particular type so you could never guarantee that.

I'm certain you could refine the pattern above to make it more usable, maybe even automate bits of it (can we write a generic `upcast` function? can TemplateHaskell generate the boilerplate for us?). If you threw in constraints like `Typeable` into the mix you should even be able to get runtime-checked downcasts if you really want, and might be able to implement an equality operator that worked (returning `False` for different concrete types and delegating to `==` when the types do match). But personally I'm not terribly inclined to try to flesh this out further.

TLDR: OO style classes (ignoring mutations) are basically a particular combination of type classes, types holding member data, existential types, with a whole lot of default machinery to make it work easily instead of being a huge pain. Given that Haskell gives you each of those pieces as orthogonal minimal concepts, I find it much easier to know and understand those concepts separately and apply them individually or in concert *as they are needed*, rather than to take OO's swiss-army-knife approach and try to force every program to fit the facilities provided by that structure.

Comment: And I thought my attempt was ugly.  Wow, I asked for it to be made cleaner not worse ;-).  But I think you TL;DR (which doesn't just summarize but introduces a new concept .... more minus points from your professor for that) is the answer "much easier to ... apply them [OO concepts] individually ... as they are needed"