# Haskell alternative to virtual methods and method inheritance

Tags: haskell, inheritance

Let's say I have something like this in Java:

```
class A {
    int v;
    public A(int v) {
        this.v = v;
    }
    public int a() {
        return v;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public B(int v) { 
        super(v);
    }
    @Override
    public int a() {
        return super.a() + 5;
    }
}
```

How could I do something similar in Haskell? I have a very basic understanding what typeclasses are. I would like to have something like `ArrayList<A>` of objects (or just `[A]` in Haskell) with virtual methods, which would be inherited from the superclass.

Comment: Object-oriented programming and functional programming are very different. You can't expect what makes sense in one paradigm to translate smoothly to the other; while it is possible to encode objects with inheritance into Haskell it's not pretty. If you can give a more concrete example of what you're trying to achieve in reality - beyond "hello world" - we might be able to give more help on how to achieve that in a functional style.

Comment: Haskell lacks nominal subtyping which makes this impossible to translate directly. In Haskell, you could model a similar system by writing `data B = B A` and `instance Something B where something (B a) = something a + 5`. Of course, there are other ways - what you would actually do depends on your particular use case, which is impossible to discern from this toy example.

Comment: @Benjamin Hodgson thank you for yout answer, I would like to implement a  simple simulation of life. In this simulation have to be objects/creatures with different behavior but they have to inherit some kind of parent creature. In imperative languages with OOP it can be easily achieved with super calls, but I don't understand how to do it in haskell.

Comment: @Artem Sounds like your different "creatures" might fit naturally into the cases of a datatype: `data Creature = Cat | Horse | Unicorn | ...`

Comment: @Benjamin Hodgson I may be very wrong, but to me it doesn't seem to be a good idea to hardcode everything to one level of inheritance. I don't understand how to implement the following: a creature has a method to change its state based on the current state of the world, as I understand, in haskell it has to be `tick :: Creature -> World -> Creature`, and again, how do I implement "inheritance" of such a function for different kinds of creatures?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object Oriented Polymorphism in Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005419/object-oriented-polymorphism-in-haskell)

Comment: @Artem You could do something along these lines: `data Creature = Creature { name :: String, age :: Int, tick :: Creature -> World -> Creature, ...}; ancestor :: Creature; ancestor = Creature { name = ..., age = ..., tick = ... }`. Haskell can be pretty decent at prototype-based OO

Comment: @David Young I suppose I'll do it like that and there would be only inheritance of constructor functions to create 'creatures'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's kind of a "pattern" that works like this:

```
data Animal m = Animal {
  makeSound :: m ()
}

cat = Animal {
  makeSound = print "Meow!"
}

dog = Animal {
  makeSound = print "Woof!"
}

cow = Animal {
  makeSound = print "Moo!"
}


animals = [cat, cat, dog, cow]

main = mapM_ makeSound animals
```

Using this pattern you can do some more-or-less crazy things such as:

```
import Data.Maybe

data I a = I {
  f :: a,
  sup :: Maybe (I a)
}

mkA = I { f = 10,  sup = Nothing }

mkB = let a = mkA in I { 
   f = 5 + f a,
   sup = Just a
 }

ls = [mkA, mkB, fromJust $ sup mkB]

main = mapM_ (print . f) ls
```

This pattern can also be used to achieve "factory"-like functionality like:

```
import Data.IORef

data Storage m a = Storage {
  putData :: String -> m (),
  readData :: m String
}

fileStorage path = Storage {
  putData = \s -> writeFile path s,
  readData = readFile path
}

inMemStorage ref = Storage {
  putData = \s -> writeIORef ref s,
  readData = readIORef ref
}

readStorage storage = readData storage

chooseStorage "file" = return $ fileStorage "tmp.txt"
chooseStorage "mem" = do
  r <- newIORef ""
  return $ inMemStorage r

main = do
  storage <- chooseStorage "mem"
  putData storage "hi there"
  txt <- readData storage
  print txt
```

Basically you define a data type that has functions as its members and then define "constructors" (which are just regular functions) that return an instance of that data type.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I wanted, and I have already done it like you suggested.