# Abstract factories in Haskell

Tags: haskell, design-patterns

I was wondering how to implement the Abstract Factory design pattern, common in object-oriented languages, in a functional language. In particular, I am interested in an Haskell implementation.

I tried to implement the pattern using type classes:

```
class Product p where
  toString :: p -> String

class Factory f where
  createProduct :: Product p => f -> p

data FirstProduct = FirstProduct
data FirstFactory = FirstFactory

instance Product FirstProduct where
  toString _ = "first product"

instance Factory FirstFactory where
  createProduct _ = FirstProduct
```

When compiling this code, the following error is returned instead:

```
Could not deduce (p ~ FirstProduct)
from the context (Product p)
  bound by the type signature for
             createProduct :: Product p => FirstFactory -> p
  at test.hs:14:3-15
  ‘p’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for
        createProduct :: Product p => FirstFactory -> p
      at test.hs:14:3
Relevant bindings include
  createProduct :: FirstFactory -> p (bound at test.hs:14:3)
In the expression: FirstProduct
In an equation for ‘createProduct’: createProduct _ = FirstProduct
```

It looks like the compiler is not happy with the implementation of `createProduct`, and in particular with its return value. I though that returning any instance of the `Product` type class could do the trick, but it obviously doesn't.

I would like to know if something similar to an Abstract Factory can be implemented in Haskell or if my approach is completely wrong. Are there any other "patterns" I could use to achieve a similar result?

**Edit**

According to the suggestions and explanations of leftaroundabout, I came up with a different solution that fulfills my needs without misusing type classes. The solution could be probably be improved, but at the moment this is the best I was able to achieve.

The library would have to define something similar to the following:

```
data ProductSystem p = ProductSystem {create :: p, toString :: p -> String }

productUser :: ProductSystem p -> String
productUser system = toString system $ create system
```

Some users of the library could provide "implementations" of the `ProductSystem` for their concrete needs:

```
data FirstProduct = FirstProduct

firstSystem :: ProductSystem FirstProduct
firstSystem = ProductSystem create toString
  where 
    create = FirstProduct
    toString p = "first"

data SecondProduct = SecondProduct

secondSystem :: ProductSystem SecondProduct
secondSystem = ProductSystem create toString
  where
    create = SecondProduct
    toString p = "second"
```

Somewhere else, the two pieces could be unified to execute the wanted behavior:

```
productUser firstSystem
productUser secondSystem
```

Comment: The abstract factory pattern is more or less a ridiculously convoluted way of working yourself around a language's inability so simply define **a function**. Why would you need that in Haskell? — More objective remark: Haskell type classes are _not_ a good drop-in for something that's a class in an OO language. If you want to model something like Abstract Factory in Haskell, you'd probably better use `data` for the "classes".

Comment: The type of `createProduct` indicates it can create any instance of `Product` while the implementation can only return instances of `FirstProduct`.

Comment: For more info on how to (not) do OO in Haskell, consider https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/OOP_vs_type_classes,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184286/object-oriented-programming-in-haskell/20188103, and https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/.

Comment: I could use `data` to define sets of factories and products, but this would limit the extensibility of my system. If I define `data Factory = FirstFactory | SecondFactory`, then my library is only limited to those two implementations. I would like instead to define a `Factory` API I could rely on, so that users of my library could provide different implementations of it. Can you explain how to use functions to achieve a similar goal?

Comment: No no, you just define one record: for all that's _needed_ from `Product`, i.e. for the results of all its _interface methods_. (In your example, this is basically just a single `String`). Everything that would have to be fields or methods of derived classes isn't really needed in Haskell: that kind of stuff can be automatically packed in closures of the functions ("factories") with which you generate your `Product`s. It's actually a lot like the "ad-hoc-object-orientation" that some dynamic languages offer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*As I already commented, the whole idea is futile: you don't need abstract factories in Haskell. But that aside, here's why your particular attempt doesn't compile.*

---

The signature

```
  createProduct :: Product p => f -> p
```

means not what you apparently think: in Java, this would say "I'll generate some object of a subclass of `Product`, don't ask which though." In Haskell – whose subclasses are *not* subtypes! – this means, "for *any* (specific!) instance of `Product` that you request, I'll give you an object of that concrete type." Which isn't possible, since `FirstFactory` apparently can't supply a `SecondProduct`.

To express what you tried to say, you need an explicit wrapper to contain "any subclass". We call that an *existential*, it's written thus:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs       #-}

data AnyProduct where
  AnyProduct :: Product p => p -> AnyProduct
```

with this, you can write

```
class Factory f where
  createProduct :: f -> AnyProduct
```

For some `yourProduct :: AnyProduct`, you can then "call the `toString` method" this way:

```
      ...
      productString = case yourProduct of
                        AnyProduct p -> toString p
      ...
```

But since this is actually *the only thing* you can do with an `AnyProduct` value (like in OO language, you can't access fields/methods of the unknown subclass), the whole `AnyProduct` type is actually completely equivalent to `String` alone! And by the same argument, `AnyFactory` would again be equivalent to that. So basically, the entire code you posted is equivalent to

```
type Product = String
```

...

Existentials are quite [generally frowned upon](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/), you should only use them in special cases, not for anything just because OO languages do it with subclassing.

Comment: This seems interesting, but as you stated before my problem could be solved with much simpler constructs. I edited my question to add another solution that came to my mind. Anyway, today I definitely learnt something!