# Can Hana's mechanism for customizing behavior via tag-dispatching be seen as a form of adapter pattern?

Tags: c++, functional-programming, adapter, template-meta-programming, boost-hana

### tl;dr

Is the customization of `boost::hana::transform` for `std::vector` (via specializing `boost::hana::tranform_impl` for the tag `ext::std::vector`) a form of ***Adaptor pattern*** that wraps the STL's `std::transform` into Hana's interface function `boost::hana::transform`?

### Why this question

I'm reading [*Dive into Design Patterns*](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/book), and I'm a bit bothered by the fact that this resource, just like any others I've been peeping into (including [*Head First - Design Patterns*](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/head-first-design/0596007124/ch01.html)), doesn't have a single page, probably not even a paragraph, that doesn't contain the words *inheritance*/*virtual*/*extend*/etc, just like inheritance is the only way to understand and use design patterns.

In an attempt to get a less inheritance-biased understanding of what these infamous patterns are, I'm trying to look at them from other perspectives, by asking what they look like in functional programming languages like Haskell (e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66393236/5825294)), or, with the present question, if a use of such patters is present in libraries which make use of a lot of template meta-programming, such as [Boost.Hana](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/).

### The question

If you look at [`/usr/include/boost/hana/ext/std/vector.hpp`](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/blob/master/include/boost/hana/ext/std/vector.hpp), there's some (commented) code for making `std::vector` a functor in the way that Hana defines it, i.e. by specializing the `transform_impl` template for `std::vector` (well, actually for the tag `ext::std::vector` which is associated to any `std::vector<T>`).

The specialization obviously resorts to `std::transform` (and some template tricks/`enable_if`) to get the job done.

The net effect, however, is that if I uncomment that code, then I'm able to use `boost::hana::transform` on `std::vector`, which I couldn't do without uncommenting that code.

On the other hand, `std::vector` is conceptually a functor whether or not I have `boost::hana::transform` at my disposal. Indeed, `std::transform` exists in the STL, and the "only" drawback is that it's not usable in a functional way because it's iterator-based.

Therefore, it looks to me that customizing `boost::hana::transform` for `std::vector` (via specializing `boost::hana::tranform_impl` for the tag `ext::std::vector`) is a bit like adapting the STL interface to functors, `std::transform`, to Hana's interface, `boost::hana::transform`.

Is this a valid interpretation?

### The code

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/osqeKv) is a use-case and solution inspired to the [linked open source book](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/book).

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/ejfYEf) is the same use-case where I've used (hopefully correctly) the Hana approach to solve it. Since it solves the same problem, I'm tempted to self-answer that it is indeed a case of Adaptor pattern.

Comment: That seems reasonable.  A problem is often that design patterns in a book like that are strict subsets of what you might consider reasonable, so... maybe not.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont, _maybe not_ what?

Comment: Maybe that isn't what that particular design pattern book says that design pattern is.  I find pattern names are often games in "no, this particular thing makes it this pattern" if you play definition games.

Comment: `hana::transform` would have been named `map` or `fmap`, but was named `transform` to be more palatable to C++ programmers. `hana::transform` is like a more generic version of `std::transform` the same way that Functor is more general than Range